# SonataAdmin - configure rouites depends of security

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Where can i change available routes depends of user ROLES ?

when i add

```
public function configureRoutes(AdminInterface $admin, RouteCollection $collection){

if(!$this->configurationPool->getContainer()->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIM')){
 $collection->remove('create');

}
```

this is cached when build so for admin create route not exist.

Comment: For all reasonable intents and purposes you can't.  As you say the routes are all cached and really can't be changed on a request by request basis.  I guess in theory you could dynamically add routes but that gets very tricky.  Typically you would use the access_control section of security.yaml to control authorizations.  Or maybe configure multiple firewalls.  Or if you really have something unusual going on then you can add a kernel request/controller listener and add whatever code you need to authorize routes.  Really depends on why you feel you need to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Since you are not changing routes here, but controlling access to them I suggest to follow Cerad's hint and control access in security.yaml.